# Typescript: typing many similar export values

Tags: typescript, types

I have a module, that contains handlers for my API calls. It looks something like this:

```js
// ./handlers.ts
export function handler1({ api }) { /* ... */ }
export function handler2({ api, config }) { /* ... */ }
export function handler3({ api }) { /* ... */ }
```

```js
// ./index.ts
import * as handlers from './handlers'

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const handler = determineHandlerName()
  if(handler in handlers) {
    handlers[handler](api)
  }
})
```

Is there an elegant way to tell typescript the `handlers` object looks like this?

```js
interface Handlers {
  [key: string]: (Api) => void
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of TypeScript 3.6+, the type of `handler[keyOfHandlers]` is inferred like this:

```
import * as handlers from './handlers'

declare const handlerName: keyof typeof handlers;

const handler = handlers[handlerName];

/*
handler: (({ api }: { api: any; }) => void)
         | (({ api, config }: { api: any; config: any; }) => void)
         | (({ api }: { api: any; }) => void)
*/
```

So, the type of `handlers` object is *technically correct* as it is inferred.

The problem is in this place:

```
if (handler in handlers) {
  // Here, `handler` still has type `string`,
  // which is the opposite of what we want.

  // We could do this, however:
  const handlerName = handler as keyof typeof handlers;
  handlers[handlerName]({ api });
}
```

The problem, as we can see, is that TypeScript does not guard the type of `handler` string after `if (handler in handlers)`.

Another solution to this would be creating a custom type guard:

```
const isKeyOf = <T>(key: any, obj: T): key is keyof T => key in obj;

// then:
if (isKeyOf(handler, handlers)) {
  handlers[handler](api); // works fine
}
```